# How do I make a simple shortcut on my Mac to go to screen saver mode?

Tags: macos, unix, keyboard

I just want to push 2 buttons at the same time to go to screen saver mode.

Is there a setting for that in system preferences where I can set my keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

See [Assign a shortcut to running a script in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/153898#153898)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to bring up the screen saver to lock your computer, you can achieve the same thing with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>, which makes the screen dark (and locks the computer).

Comment: But only if *System Preferences — Security — General — ☑ Require password [immediately] after sleep or screen saver begins*.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://leafraker.com/2007/09/14/start-the-screen-saver-with-quicksilver/ It describes how to use QuickSilger to trigger the screen saver using a keyboard shortcut.