# How to create a service to zip files in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, services, automator

I have to create services for two different use cases:

1. Mark a folder or file and zip it using an archiver tool such as rar7zip.
2. Mark a text and open a translator app.

I've been trying to use Automator and but when selecting the new added service from Services context menu nothing happens. When I look at `~/Library/Services` I do see my new services but with `workflow` extension and not `service`.

The steps I did for creating a service for the first use case:

1. In Automator - select *Service*
2. Drag the relevant app from the Applications folder
3. Choose: "files or folders" in the appropriate drop down and Finder.app in the second drop down.

[image]

For the second use case I selected "text" and "any application".

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to provide the exact names and links to the programs you want to control.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the first one:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4922553/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-26%20at%2012.08.36%20PM.png

Comment: and here's the link for the second: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4922553/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-26%20at%2012.11.23%20PM.png

Comment: See my answer. By dragging files and folders onto Automator, you just *select them for further processing*, e.g. moving them somewhere, or renaming them, as indicated by the *Get Specified Finder Items* title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag an application to Automator, you're creating a *Get Specified Finder Items* action. Don't drag them onto Automator, but launch them e.g. from a *Run Shell Script* or *Run AppleScript* action. The *Launch Application* action does not accept file arguments in my testing.

Using *Run Shell Script*, which receives *input as arguments*, it looks like this (using CleanArchiver as a substitute):

```
open -a CleanArchiver "$@"
```

It also depends on your application what they do when they receive files as input. If your archiver (which I won't buy to test this) automatically bundles them up, you're good. Otherwise you need to workaround the program's limitations.

Note that you can create `.zip` archives from any file selection's context menu in Finder.

---

It's not possible to pass *selected text* as arguments to a program launched e.g. using *Launch Application*. You need it to be AppleScriptable, or first e.g. write the text to a file. It depends on the application (which you don't even mention). Some options I mention in [this](https://superuser.com/a/177124/22317) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/296429/22317) answer, using web sites in both cases.

Note that for *Translation Tab*, you already *have a service* that can translate the selection, and don't need to create one yourself. See the App Store screenshots. It's called *Translate Selection with Translate Tab*.