# Keyboard shortcut to unhide or unminimize a window in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dock, window-manager

I know how to Hide (`Cmd+H`) or Minimize (`Cmd+M`) a focused window in OS X, but I can't find a keyboard shortcut or even a menu item to restore, unhide, unminimize, or otherwise show a window that I've hidden or minimized.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: In OS X Mavericks (10.9.2), Cmd-Tab to the app that is Hidden (with previous Cmd-H) to restore it. (This doesn't work for Minimized windows.)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

This way requires a bit of practice:

- press <kbd>⌘ ⇥</kbd> (Command-Tab) to show your running apps. Keep holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>.
- press <kbd>⇥</kbd> until you've selected the minimized app
- press the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Option) key, and let go of the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key. You must release the Command key *after* pressing the Option key!

Note that this only works for an app with all of its windows minimized. If there is already a visible window of the app you won't be able to get to the minimized one with this trick.

Comment: Kudos to @evaneykelen! I'll agree that this is the best answer.  But de-kudos to Apple... the 'Note' in the answer & the uncomfortable shortcut trick are the reason why I still have [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) bound to my ⌥ ⇥ (Option-Tab) keys

Comment: "You must depress the Command key after pressing the Option key!"

This is confusing - how can you depress the Command key if you were already holding it in?

Comment: @tnorthcutt: I realize it sounds confusing but it's really how it works. With most keyboard shortcuts it does not matter when you release the keys involved but it's a crucial element of this shortcut trick.

Comment: Great tip but can you check @tnorthcutt 's comment please?  I think he has a point, you don't depress the Command key in step 3.  This would all be much clearer if you deleted the last sentence from step 3.

Comment: Edited: "depress" -> "release"

"depress... [You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.](http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/1-b7RmmMJeo?start=45.0&end=54.5&version=3&autoplay=1)"

Comment: That's so un-intuitive. cmd-tab to select, then cmd-m again to unhide it. (like a toggle). Because a lot of times you don't know you have minimized it until you released the cmd key! Now you have to cmd-tab forward and back then do the cmd-alt release.

Comment: So... Someone at Apple thought this was a good idea, did they?

Comment: @mskw Yeah it's so stupid. There are so many things about this OS that indicate it is a half baked scheme they stopped working on.

Comment: nice, but this the very interesting shortcut. I feel like a piano player while holding these keys :D

Comment: it works but there's no way to know that the window I'm going for is minimized, so maybe you need to start using this trick every time just in case the window is indeed hidden

Comment: Didn't work for me on Sonomo 14.1.1.

Answer (score 133):

To restore one of many minimized windows using only the keyboard:

1. Start with a minimized window
2. Cmd + tab to the application icon (Continue to hold Cmd).
3. Tip: After pressing Cmd + tab once, you can also use arrow left (and right) when holding the Cmd key, to quickly go to the application. This is a handy combination with the next step.
4. While holding Cmd, push the up (or down) arrow key on the keyboard. This will bring up a list of all the application's windows (You can release key command key once the window list view comes up if you like)
5. Push the down arrow key to select the minimized windows.
6. Use the left and right arrow keys to select the minimized window you want
7. Push enter to restore the window and bring it into focus (make it the selected window)

(Tested on OSX Mountain Lion. Step 2b tested on MacOS Sierra)

Comment: Agree! I like this answer much better.  Especially considering that I have cmd + arrow switch between tabs in chrome!  +1

Comment: Ok - yeah. I works... But who uses the arrow-keys? Ideally, I want to be able to do this with only my left hand. Why don't Apple just make me CMD-Tab with my left hand, hold down the 'Down-arrow' with my right hand and press the number '8' with my nose. This is ridiculous!!

Comment: I don't see a step 2b? Tested on High Sierra 10.13 - works!

Comment: Thank you, it works. Apple knows how to complicate things which is already simple.

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer, thanks! The only problem is it does not work if you are currently in full screen view with an app. This includes single and multiple monitors, so any monitors that are in full screen mode will not display windows of the desired app while using this feature. *The monitor with the dock* must be on a desktop screen before following the above steps in order to unminimize a window.

Comment: You can do this in fewer steps by using Ctrl + Down arrow to see all the current apps windows. Minimised windows will be at the bottom and by using the arrow keys you can navigate to the one you need and hit enter to restore it.

Answer (score 35):

Another option is to press `⌃F3` (`fn^F3` on a MacBook) to bring focus to the dock. From there you can navigate `left`/`right`/`up`/`down` to select the window you want to unminimize.

Comment: Yeah. That's endedup being the most common method I use. Except, I assigned a new key combo (I use: cmd + alt + ctrl + down arrow) to focus the dock, the start typing the name if the app and it goes to it. Hitting return brings it to the front. It works just fine, but still I wish there was a more symmetrical method baked in.

Comment: It doesn't work. Neither Command+W, nor Command+H hidden window couldn't be restored. :(

Comment: With Cmd-W and Cmd-H you need to go to the application icon rather than the minimized window icon.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. You can remap this in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control > Application windows`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my system (macos catalina 10.15.1).   Sure F3 brings up a list of grouped windows, but cannot navigate within the group, either with tabs, arrow keys or whatever.

Answer (score 17):

I always hide applications instead of minimizing windows:

- Just focusing the application again unhides it
- There is no animation
- When an application has multiple windows, I often want to show or hide them as a group
- I keep the Dock hidden, and it would be easy to forget minimized windows in the Dock

Anyway, here are a few (probably not that useful) scripts for unminimizing windows. You can [assign shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) to them with an application like FastScripts or Alfred.

This unminimizes all windows of the current application:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    try
        set miniaturized of windows to false -- most applications
    end try
    try
        set collapsed of windows to false -- at least Finder
    end try
end tell
```

If minimizing to application icons is not enabled, you could also click the last Dock icon:

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (last UI element of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

This clicks the dock icons of all minimized windows:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    click (UI elements of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
end tell
```

Comment: !!  Nice work!  The 'Dock Click' version above (second one) is not as reliable depending on if my app is stuck in the dock or not, minmized windows are stacked, etc.  I modified the script to toggle the state (if minimized then unminimize and vice versa), saved it as a service via Automator.  However, it takes about 30+ seconds after hitting the shortcut keys until the action actually occurs.

Comment: First, the delay is only when running it as a service created in Automator.  When I run it in Applescript Editor it's lightning fast!  As for the Dock stuff... I've got my minimized windows set to hide behind their app icon (aka they don't show to the far right), so it was still working for apps that are not set to 'Keep in Dock'

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for months! Makes my workflow so much more "flowy".

Answer (score 8):

To show a window that you've hidden with ⌘H, you can unhide it and bring it back to the foreground by switching to it with ⌘⇥ along with perhaps ⌘`.

A clunky way to bring up a window minimized using ⌘M is to bring up the Application Exposé using F10, then navigate down to the realm of minimized windows to select the one you want to restore.

Comment: I think this is about the best option when ⌘H Hiding an app... I just get annoyed that there's no native solution to restore a ⌘M Minimized window.  When I Minimize a window, then Cmd+Tab back to that app... I can't find a shortcut to get the minimized window back.

Comment: @brandonjp: I've edited my answer to include one way of restoring a minimized window. I think it's a bit inefficient, personally, but it's a bit easier than a touchpad sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

**Keyboard shortcuts:**

1. Hold down `⌘ + Tab`
2. While holding down `⌘`, hit `Tab` to move to the app you are interested in
3. While holding down `⌘`, hit the `▲` arrow to make the window thumbnails appear at the bottom
4. While holding down `⌘`, hit the `▼` arrow to move the the bottom row where all the other windows are open
5. Let go of `⌘` and move left or right to select the window
6. Hit `Enter`

**Trackpad shortcuts:**

1. Configure it

   1. `System Preferences » Trackpad » App Expose » Swipe down with three fingers`
2. Use it

   1. Swipe down with three fingers to make the window thumbnails appear at the bottom
   2. Click the window you are interested in

Comment: And sometimes Mac App Expose´ stops working. To fix it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150650/58582

Comment: This works. I never noticed myself that bottom row with small icons, that you can use the down arrow to navigate to.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Cmd-L` to unminimize a window.

But I think it only works if you don't have another window of the same application open.

Answer (score 5):

Some applications bind commands to their windows (Terminal comes to mind, but iTunes also with Cmd-Opt-1/2), you can restore those that way.

You want [**Witch**](http://manytricks.com/witch/) for the kind of functionality you want. And having the zoom button accessible via keyboard is also pure bliss.

You can't hide windows, only applications. Unhide via Cmd-Tab (the hidden applications are to the right, so use Cmd-Shift-Tab to start there).

You can always open the Help menu's text field and type the window name (if you know it) to access its Window menu sub-item.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Witch for a couple years now, and really love it.  Just hoping that there was a native shortcut for bring minimized windows back to life.

Comment: Now where would then be the reason to use and appreciate Witch? :-) No native way except where the programmers explicitly thought of it.

Comment: Of course, you can always use Cmd-? for the search field and type the window's name. Thinking about it, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: what is the zoom button you speak of?

Comment: @Eddified: The third, green window button (close, minimize, zoom). It doesn't always maximize, so it's not called that.

Comment: Remember to log out and in, after installing Witch. That took me quite a while to figure that out (sadly). But blessing to Witch from me.

Answer (score 0):

Its simpler:

1. You know `⌘ + Tab` shows app icons, and helps to switch between. And `⌘ + Shift + Tab` does the same in reverse order.
2. Press `⌘ + H` to Hide while the `⌘ + Tab` has the highlight on the desired app icon.
3. Pressing `⌘ + H` also unhides (or brings it back).

So, just put `⌘ + Tab` and `⌘ + H` to your muscle memory.

But the problem is, `⌘ + H` doesnt unhide if the window was minimized using pointing device. In this case, use  `⌘(hold) + Option(Hold) + release ⌘ and Option at the same time`. I try not to use trackpad for minimising, because `⌘ + H` seems simple and easy.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Spotlight Search** `cmd+space`, start typing the app name and press enter. It will switch to the open app and unhide/un-minimize the window. However as @GenePavlosky pointed out, this only brings one minimized window to the forefront.

Comment: Works for an app with a single window. But e.g. I have two VS Code windows open, minimize one of them. Doing what you said just brings up the non-minimized window, while the other one stays minimized.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky In that case, I usually switch the other window with CMD+` after call the application by spotlight ^^; I came here when I didn't use my two hands on the keyboard and the answer is the one using CMD+Tab and option key with one hand.

Comment: @kakadais I don't get what you're saying. Cmd+` toggles between unminimized windows of an app. It ignores the minimized window(s). Just tried it with Firefox and VS Code. Ashwin's answer works, though.