# Can I change the minimize button action to 'hide' instead of default minimize in mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, macbook-pro

I'd like that the yellow button at the top left corner of a window will hide it - without keeping an extra window icon at the dock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, just a heads-up, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will hide the active application.

Since you mentioned that you'd like to keep the application from adding an extra icon to the dock when you minimize, this is a solution.

Visit `System Preferences -> Dock` and check the box labeled "Minimize windows into application icon". Checking this option produces the obvious result leaving you with less dock icons when applications are minimized.

[image]

Comment: I prefer this behaviour, but note that it is not the same as hiding. Tabbing back to the application will still require modifier juggling. See http://superuser.com/questions/196141/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x

Comment: Hiding and minimize are two different actions in macOS, as hiding will remove *all* windows of that app from view, as well as not minimizing to the dock or app icon. For people who want to hide all windows, this answer will not be of use.

Answer (score 1):

One main reason for true Hide instead of Minimize to Dock is that with Hide you can bring the window up when cyckling through apps with Command + Tab. Would love to set the yellow button to hide.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1104827)