# How to I use Apple Script to change the keyboard layout on Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, applescript, automator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch TO specific input source](https://superuser.com/questions/224161/switch-to-specific-input-source)

I want to do something like:
`set keyboard layout to 'QWERTY'` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The current keyboard layout appears to be saved in ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*machineid*.plist under the key `AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID`.  Your ID is a 12-digit hexadecimal number. Inspect the ByHost folder to see what I mean.

You can write preferences to this file using the `defaults` command in Terminal. For example, the following commands change this preference to the US keyboard then restart `SystemUIServer`, the process that handles the Input Source menu.

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.0017f2c31710 AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID -string "com.apple.keylayout.US"
killall SystemUIServer
```

However, this seems to change the keyboard only about 80% of the time.

You can run Terminal commands from AppleScript easily using [do shell script](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=44110) may be useful, you'll need to change the names. It may be out of date, if it is [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Keyboard-Language-of-a-Mac) is the newer workflow. It's odd, no-one seems to have done this in the last five or so years.