# Applescript in Automator to Service

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to do this very simple Applescript for text manipulation.

[image]

It runs from the service menu, in some applications. Questions:

1. What's wrong with my script?
2. Sometimes it shows up in the services menu and sometimes it doesn't. Any advice on this?

My goal is [to do this with pure Applescript](https://superuser.com/a/227217/4952), but this first step is the hard one.

Comment: Should work fine. Where exactly doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right now all apps are showing "No services apply" in the services menu from TextMate or Sublime Text 2 or Evernote. Not sure how to proceed. Sorry, evernote is showing  some services, but not the new one I created.

Comment: @slhck the services do appear in system preferences, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input type is set to text, so the service is only available when there's a text selection. Try changing it to no input (and reopening applications).

Comment: I change it to "no input" or select some text and it appears in the menu and works +1. But even with "no input" selected, it only appears in the menu when some text is selected. Any way to get it to work without selecting text?

Comment: Did you try quitting and reopening applications after changing the input type?

Comment: Definitely did. This whole thing is very confusing. Not sure why, but with Quicksilver it all works really well. I couldn't get Fastscripts to work nor this solution. Anyway, I'll close this question for now.

Comment: Loving Spark right now http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php, BTW