# How to activate global shortcut to launch an application on Mac?

Tags: macos, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting application with custom keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/245711/starting-application-with-custom-keyboard-shortcut)

I want to launch Terminal app with Command+T on anywhere. (global shortcut)
How can I achieve this?

Comment: For one thing. You probably don't want to use Command+T for terminal. It is used in many apps.

Comment: @Mark You're right. The key is bound to many apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Automator to create a service that launches Terminal, and then assign your keyboard shortcut from System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services.

Comment: It seems require some kind of target object to interact with. But I want absolute execution without any object... However it does not seem to be no other way.