# Operating Skype from the keyboard in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

I have a Mac, and I would like to operate Skype from the keyboard.

Is there any site with shortcuts summarized? Or can someone publish them here?

I'm interested in stuff like bringing Skype up with a hotkey (or just the contact list) and then open a conversation from the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing Skype up with a hotkey *only* isn't possible in OS X — at least not without workarounds. There are many applications / resources regarding assigning one application to a hotkey, including [this one](https://superuser.com/q/245711/48078).

You'll easily find all the shortcuts Skype has to offer in its menus. Here's the most important stuff.

#### Switching between Skype's main windows:

- Press ⌘1 to (de)activate the main window
- Press ⌘2 to show the dial pad
- Press ⌘3 to show the contact list

#### Creating a new conversation:

- Press ⌘N to open a new untitled conversation

  - Type the contact name
  - Then press ↑ or ↓ until you reach the name you want to add
  - Press ↩ to add the contact
  - Repeat to add further contacts
- Once you're in the conversation, press ⇧⌘A to add further contacts
- Press ⌘W to close an open conversation

#### Switching between conversations:

- Press ⌥⌘← or ⌥⌘→ to switch between all open conversations