# Is there a Keyboard Shortcut to launch TERMINAL?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting application with custom keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/245711/starting-application-with-custom-keyboard-shortcut)

I just want to call my `Terminal` with a shortcut.

- I just want a Keyboard Shortcut for `Terminal`
- No `spotlight` or launchbar icon or any other solution rather than a direct Keyboard Shortcut is needed

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54/is-there-a-way-to-start-the-terminal-with-a-keyboard-short-cut