# Stop minimized windows from opening when application gets focus in OS X

Tags: mac, google-chrome, window

Let's say I have one window open in Chrome but it's minimized (I want to save it for later reading). I want to open a new tab in a new window. If the minimized window is the only window I have open in Chrome, when the Chrome application gains the focus (on Mac), the window pops up. I then have to minimize it and open a new tab in a new window.

Is there a way to force Chrome to open a new tab in a new window when it gets the focus, instead of opening the minimized window?

Comment: This isn't really specific to Chrome. You could simplify the question by removing (most) references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the application switcher (⌘⇥).

You could also [assign a shortcut for an Applescript](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/264943#264943) like `activate application "Google Chrome"`.

Clicking an application's Dock icon sends the equivalent of `reopen` in Applescript. If there's no open windows or documents, it opens a new one. If all windows are minimized, it unminimizes the first one of them. The application switcher behaves like `activate` in Applescript.

Many applications also have items like *New Window* in their Dock context menu.

Comment: Oh! That's really silly of me. I'm too used to switching windows with Witch. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinBurke At least LiteSwitchX has a checkbox for *Switching sends re-open event*, but there's apparently no equivalent in Witch. ⌘N would be pretty handy in application switchers though. (Or separate actions for activating and reopening.)

Answer (score 1):

Just open a new window.  On Linux and Windows, you do Ctrl+N, and I'm sure it's similar on Mac (try Command+N or just use the menu for opening a new Window).

Comment: Yes, but I'd like the minimized window to stay minimized when Chrome gains the focus. The problem is that when Chrome gains the focus the minimized window pops up. This is annoying.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking (or whatever the equivalent is if you don't have that enabled) on the Chrome icon in your dock?  I think you can open a new window from there.