# Assign a shortcut for creating and opening a dated text file on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-lion, services

I used to use tomboy wiki and they allowed you to bind opening a new note to a keyboard combination.

I use emacs on Lion and I want replicate this behaviour. I want to visit a new/existing file in my projects folder named yyyymmdd.md by pressing shift-z-command anywhere.

It might be possible to use automator to run a shell script that gets the iso date and then appends the directory path and `.md` at the end. Then it calls emacs with those arguments. As a service I can assign it to a keyboard combination. But I have no idea how to complete the steps exactly.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
f="$HOME/Desktop/$date.md"
[[ ! -f "$f" ]] && echo $'## $date\n' > "$f"
# emacs "$f"
open "$f" -a Aquamacs
```

And [Assign a shortcut to running a script in OS X - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943)

Comment: I believe emacs just visits the file. If it doesn't exist it is created.

Comment: If you want to open an emacs app you can just use record using applescript, then run it with `osascript -e `.

Comment: @Fire Only a few apps (like Finder and BBEdit) support recording AppleScripts.  `open -a SomeApp` is pretty much equivalent to `osascript -e $'tell app "SomeApp"\nreopen\nactivate\nend tell'`. `osascript` is a lot slower though.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can use open -a Emacs with a filename?

Comment: If you mean the graphical Emacs.app, then yeah.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I did; it's time to turn it into an apple script. I also have to figure out how test if a file !exist, then create file with `## YYYYMMDD\n`

Comment: You removed the applescript `.scpt` part placed into the scripts directory to launch from fastscripts.

Comment: @Fire Huh? I just edited out the note to `chmod u+x /path/to/script`. And you can also use FastScripts to run shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any freeware that does this, but here are some shareware apps :

http://nulana.com/shortcuts

http://www.alfredapp.com/ - You need the paid powerpack

http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html - Not exactly what you want, but with an action/script you can make it work.

Comment: The system it is designed is for Mac OS X.4.11? I'm on 10.7.2.

Comment: The forums is spammed and dead.

Comment: I'm going to assume the code is abandoned.

Comment: My bad... Please check the updated post.