# Is there a shortcut key to activate Caffeine on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I love caffeine, but I really wish it were just a keyboard shortcut or perhaps a command line / terminal command. Has anyone figured out a way to activate / deactivate Caffeine using another method besides clicking?

[image]

Comment: Ask the developer to implement a shortcut ? Otherwise you have two options : NO, or you can make a UI applescript hack to access the menubar and click it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caffeine has a tiny AppleScript dictionary:

```
tell application "Caffeine"
    if active then
        turn off
    else
        turn on
    end if
end tell
```

[Assign a shortcut to running a script in OS X - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943)

Comment: How can you tell what is in the application's Applescript dictionary?

Comment: @cwd Open Dictionary (⇧⌘O) in AppleScript Editor.