# Swap left/right click on OS X via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook-pro, magic-mouse

I'm looking for a way to swap the left/right button on my mouse (left/right handed person) via the Terminal.

Currently every time I want to switch this I need to go to System Preferences » Mouse » Change the option for Secondary click. It would be much easier to just run a quick command in the terminal.

I've seen things like this: 
`defaults write GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1`

**tl;dr:** Is there a way to do this sort of command (above) for the mouse's secondary click via the terminal?

My OS is 10.7.5.

Comment: Just a question. Why do you need to constantly switch? I'm just interested. Is the computer is being used bu multiple people or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant command is:

```
defaults -currentHost write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.swapLeftRightButton -bool true
```

(or "false" to set it back to normal.) *However*, I don't know of a way to get the setting to take effect without logging out & back in, which is generally more trouble than using System Preferences to make the change.

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly what I asked. I was bummed out by the fact that I had to logout/login so I did a bit of research. I'll add my finding.

Answer (score 1):

I finally went with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439705/apple-script-to-set-primary-button-secondary-button-and-other-properties-for-mo/#4537505).

Another tip that I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665692/how-can-i-add-an-applescript-menu-to-my-menubar) is to add the script to the menu bar by doing this:

1. Open AppleScripts Editor (I just search on Spotlight)
2. If you don't already have the [scripts icon](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2336/1587750787_b6e25abca3_o.jpg) in the menu bar:

   1. Click on *AppleScripts Editor* in the menu bar
   2. Click Preferences
   3. Enable the checkbox *Show Script menu in menu bar*. I personally prefer unchecking *Show Computer script*.
3. Click on the scripts icon that is now showing on your menu bar
4. Click on *Open Scripts Folder* and select *Open User Script Folder*
5. Save or copy your script file in this folder (the script I'm using can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439705/apple-script-to-set-primary-button-secondary-button-and-other-properties-for-mo/#4537505))
6. When you want to run the script just click the script icon and select the script

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler script that toggles the setting and doesn't activate System Preferences:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell radio group 1 of window 1
        if value of radio button 1 is 1 then
            click radio button 2
        else
            click radio button 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

It doesn't work with the Magic Mouse version of the preference pane.

You can save the script in AppleScript Editor and run it with `osascript script.scpt`. Or see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for different ways to assign shortcuts to scripts.

Comment: He said "via terminal".

Answer (score 0):

Can do via IOHID directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDLib.h>
#include <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDParameter.h>
#include <IOKit/hidsystem/event_status_driver.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    io_connect_t handle = NXOpenEventStatus();
    
    if (!handle) {
            printf("NXOpenEventStatus failed!\n");
            return 0;
    } 
    

    int64_t         currentButtonStatus     = 0;

    
    kern_return_t ret;
    
    IOByteCount actualSize;
    ret = IOHIDGetParameter(handle, CFSTR(kIOHIDPointerButtonMode),
        sizeof(currentButtonStatus), &currentButtonStatus, &actualSize);
    
    if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            printf("IOHIDGetParameter failed! Error %d.\n",  (int)ret);
    }
    else if (actualSize != sizeof(currentButtonStatus)) {
            printf("IOHIDGetParameter returned unexpected actualSize! (Got %d)\n", (int)actualSize);
    }
    else if (ret == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        int64_t newButtonStatus = 3 - currentButtonStatus;
        ret = IOHIDSetParameter(handle, CFSTR(kIOHIDPointerButtonMode), &newButtonStatus, sizeof(newButtonStatus));
        if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
                printf("IOHIDSetParameter failed! Error %d. (Current status = %d)\n", (int)ret, currentButtonStatus);
        }
        else {
                printf("success. Was %d, now %d.\n", currentButtonStatus, newButtonStatus);
        }
    }
    
    NXCloseEventStatus(handle);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note: Depending on OS version may need to change int64_t to int32_t.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I was able to compile this using `clang -framework IOKit -framework Foundation mouseswap.c`