# how to record frequency and timestamp of daily occurrences

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome

I want to record (by typing or hot key) the frequency of an event (ie when one smiles, hears their favorite song, sits down/stands up/whatever), and ultimately be able to analyze the data by ranges of time (ie by day, hour, week, w/e). Think of it as a powerful counter. Any programs you can suggest for this?

I would prefer OSX compatible, or online trackers

NOTES**

[WhatPulse](https://whatpulse.org//) is close, but I can't seem to track the timestamp of the key pressing

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Excel is good for doing analysis, and I presume its open source analogs are comparable.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to save the timestamps would be to [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
date '+%F %T' >> ~/Documents/log.txt
```

I don't know how to analyze the data though.