# Copy and paste plain text only in macOS?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, adobe-illustrator, plaintext

My problem: I copy something from a webpage or Illustrator, then paste it into an email or another Illustrator document and the styles are carried over from the original doc when I just want the text to conform to the format of the new document.

Is there a way to force macOS to copy and paste to only read the plaintext of my selection?

Comment: FYI, dragging text from Firefox pastes unstyled.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Usually, OS X applications allow you to paste without style using <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. This is not necessarily supported everywhere though.

If you simply want to get plain text from whatever was in the clipboard, and then put it in the clipboard again, you could for example run the following command from a Terminal:

```
pbpaste | pbcopy
```

This will get rid of rich text formatting. You could probably wrap this in a Service using *Automator.app* to have it accessible via keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Hmm, now if I could just run this as a shell script every time I copy something from Illustrator....

Comment: There's an answer, thanks to the Keyboard & Mouse pane in System Preferences. If you click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, you can assign "Paste Without Formatting" and/or "Paste and Match Style" to Command + V for all applications.
http://www.tuaw.com/2009/07/07/tuaw-tip-paste-without-formatting-by-default/

Comment: @IanAtkin That only works if the application supports this special paste mode in the first place.

Comment: @nipponese No idea how to set that up to be honest, sorry. But in theory, does that approach work?

Comment: @slhck Unfortunately I need the output to paste into Adobe Illustrator and there isn't a supported special paste command.

Comment: Update for how to do in Mavericks (cos I noticed it was different): System Preferences > Keyboard > 'Shortcuts' tab > 'App shortcuts' left pane item > click on + button > enter in the 'Menu Title:' box (and without quotes) 'Paste and Match Style', and enter the desired hotkey in the next one, click 'Add' and job is done.

Comment: I never realised that `pbpaste` and `pbcopy` exist! These will be very helpful for many uses. Thanks and an upvote!

Answer (score 41):

I'm extremely happy to have found a way to do it without using crazy shortcuts (that would annoy me more than the formatted text).

As mmdei is writing at http://ask.metafilter.com/187733/OSX-How-to-copy-plaintext-always-everywhere-without-exception

> Open 'System Preferences'
>
> Select 'Keyboard'
>
> Select tab 'Keyboard Shortcuts'
>
> Select 'Application Shortcuts' from the left listbox  Click '+' below
>   right listbox
>
> Select 'All Applications' for 'Application' input box  Type 'Paste
>   and Match Style' into the 'Menu Title' input box  In the 'Keyboard
>   Shortcut' input box, pretend that you are about to paste something by
>   typing command-v. There should now be the cloverleaf command sign
>   followed by a -v in this box.  Click add.
>
> Victory! Thanks. I should have done this myself a decade ago. =)

**ADDITION**

in case you need to paste *formatted* text, use right click - Paste.

Comment: Great answer! Small problem I faced: if you have UI language different from English, instead of "Paste and Match Style" you have to type the name of the menu item in your language.

Comment: To find name of the menu item in your language: (1) open any app with "Edit" menu equivalent like Apple Notes, Safari, Text Editor, etc., (2) open this menu and see what is visible just under "Paste" equivalent. I have, for example "Wklej i dostosuj styl".

Comment: Still sucks, because while it matches the font, it KEEPS the formatting such as bold, colors.

Answer (score 8):

As [@slhck pointed out in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/512502/167207), <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is a useful key combination that will "Paste and Match Style" in a number of apps, such as Safari, TextEdit, Mail, Messages, Notes, and even Microsoft Word (well, it does a "Paste and Match Formatting" in Word, but the result is identical as far as I can tell). One annoyance of Word's approach is that if the text you've copied is not itself styled, the <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> combination does nothing. So that's an obstacle to relying on <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to always paste unstyled text. (In Apple apps, <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> will conveniently mimic <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> if the text is unstyled.)

As far as I can tell, of Adobe CS 6, only InDesign has a "Paste without Formatting" option (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>; it uses <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for "Paste in Place").  Although you could change those keystrokes with the help of System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, that won't help you in Illustrator.

Thus, for a more all-inclusive solution, here are two methods, the first fast and graceful and the other quick and dirty.

1. Install a program that offers clipboard management (of which there are many). For example, I use the free, simple, open-source app [FlyCut](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987), which as far as I can tell always pastes unstyled text. If you adopt this solution, it sounds like you might be interested in turning off the "Sticky bezel" (in FlyCut Preferences > General) and setting your hotkey to something like <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (that's option+V) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (in FlyCut Preferences > Hotkeys). As long as those keystrokes aren't already in use for another app, the result will be that your new two-key combination will paste unstyled text system-wide. (I could not get <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to work properly with FlyCut, however, but other clipboard manager apps may do better—you could try [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com), [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com), [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com), or [others](https://gigaom.com/2009/06/02/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/), though I don't know that all paste unstyled text only as with FlyCut.)
2. For a quick-and-dirty way of clearing the styles from copied text, you can paste copied text with styles into a web browser's address bar and then copy/cut out of the address bar (although this trick should work with any field that only accepts plain text only). This works with the Safari, Chrome, and Firefox address bars (at least). Of course, this approach is far less elegant and more time-consuming than relying on a solution like #1, but it has the advantage of being easy and feasible on nearly any computer, even one you can't / don't want to install new software on.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning FlyCut, it is working great for me.

Answer (score 4):

Many applications (like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com)) that provide a clipboard history only keep the plain text versions of copied items. So you can paste from clipboard history when the frontmost application doesn't support <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Another option would be to [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
set the clipboard to (the clipboard)
```

You could also try creating `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and saving a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "~@V" = pasteAsPlainText:;
}
```

It doesn't work in Illustrator though. Most applications that support custom keybindings and rich text also have a menu bar item for pasting as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

It is working in my MacBook Air. I copied from web and pasted in my presentation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @IanAtkin comment, in “System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts,” under ”App Shortcuts, All Applications,” you can add the following:

- "Paste and Match Formatting" = <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- "Paste and Match Style" = <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

It's funny, but I had to add both. The former works in MS Word and the latter works in Evernote. Thus, if it's not working for some application, you can probably look under Edit menu and see what they call the non-formatted pasting that you want.

I also like to add:

- "Paste" =  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

So I can paste with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For my 50 cents worth, as I have a PC keyboard on my Mac, doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> whatever it is is not really feasible to do or remember. I tried swapping "Paste Without Formatting" for <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in the shortcuts, but this breaks other stuff so reverted.

My current solution is to paste all text I want to paste into a Visual Studio Code window, then cut it again, then paste it where ever.  This removes all formatting. VS Code is a free download from Microsoft, and, as a developer, I have it lying around anyway. Other text editors may work also.

Answer (score 0):

**For a 2021 solution:**

I found a free app appropriately named "Paste Plain Text." So far it's working great and is totally seamless.  It does what it claims and nothing more.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paste-plain-text/id1407015686?mt=12

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -2):

### There's a simply way to do this if you're copying from the internet.

1. Copy
2. Paste into address bar and they copy again.
3. Paste in your program.

Anytime you copy from the address bar it will remove styling.

You can also do the paste copy inside the font box in Illustrator itself instead of the address bar. That also removes styling. Illustrator example below.

[image]

Comment: I also use this approach too, but it's not always working if you have a multiline text in the clipboard

Answer (score -2):

The [Pure Paste](https://sindresorhus.com/pure-paste) app ([App Store link](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1611378436)) by [Sindre Sorhus](https://sindresorhus.com/) removes formatting automatically when you copy and paste.

[image]

**The newest app version requires macOS 14 or later.** However, you can get the last macOS 13 compatible version from the app's website.

Pure Paste lets you paste as plain text by default. It sits in the menu bar and clears formatting (fonts, colors, bold, links, tables, etc.) from the text you copy. However, it does not touch unrelated content like files, images, etc. It also ignores content copied from password managers.

The app also includes other features (only indirectly related to the OP's question) such as "optionally preserve links" or "remove tracking parameters". You'll find more on that in the [app store description](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1611378436).

I've been using this app for weeks now, and it works well for me. I used to use Flycut and paste with a `Cmd + Shift + V` key combo all the time, but with the Pure Paste app I don't have to do this anymore. And whenever I **do** want to have formatting, I just right click and paste via the context menu.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Hey @DavidPostill, thanks for the hint, I've added some more info. Wow, already 3 downvotes and a delete vote. The community of superuser.com feels quite hostile to me right now :'(

Comment: You shoudln't really quote irrelevant parts like removal of tracking params. Using some own words to describe why this is preferred is also usually nice.

Comment: @Destroy666 I've removed the irrelevant parts.