# Keyboard shortcut to applications in osx dock

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I just moved from Windows 7 to OS X and am generally very happy with the change. There is however one feature i miss after this switch: the "Windows Key" + [1-9] which opens the corresponding applications from the windows task bar.

Is there a similar feature to access applications in the osx dock directly from the keyboard?

thanks!

edit: "Windows key" was missing because i enclosed it in angle brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this after saving them in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    click UI element 3 of list 1
end tell
```

I've just used [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) to assign custom shortcuts for different applications though. Many advanced users of OS X keep the Dock hidden and switch applications with command+tab, launchers, or keyboard shortcuts.