# Launch Safari from Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari

I have a web application which has compatibility issues with MAC chrome, is there a way I can launch the same web application in Safari using any script after checking if the browser is chrome.

Thanks,

Comment: we seriously need more information on your problem, namely the name of the application.

Comment: Please, it is *Mac* (short for Macintosh), not *MAC* (Media Access Control).

Comment: @Beginner: I don't think it's possible but either way it's certainly a very ugly workaround. Surely it is better to solve the compatibility issues? What is the specific problem that prevents it working with Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a quick way to open the current tab in Safari, you could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    URL of tab 1 of window 1
end tell
tell application "Safari"
    open location result
    activate
end tell
```