# How to switch to a certain Window in OS X (opposed to application switching) using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

On a normal day I have several different windows open of all my applications. But for the sake of simplicity I will name one simple example:

1. Chrome A left side of the screen (documentation)
2. Chrome B right side of the screen (viewing result)
3. Terminal A left side of the screen (the webserver, useful when viewing results)
4. Terminal B right side of the screen (code window, I need the documentation chrome when using this).

Is there any keyboard shortcut to move Chrome A to the foreground without moving Chrome B to the foreground as well?

- With Apple-tab it switches the application and move both of them to the foreground.
- With Apple-` it switches the windows between the application so that doesn't work either.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to do this?

Desired behaviour: show Chrome A with Terminal B and Chrome B with Terminal A.

**Note that I am looking for keyboard shortcuts, NO mouse clicks :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) to select and raise only specific windows.

This would usually focus the second window in creation order:

```
set text item delimiters to linefeed
tell application "Google Chrome"
    reopen
    do shell script "sort -n <<< " & quoted form of (id of windows as text) & " | sed -n 2p"
    tell window id (result as integer) to set index to 1
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
end tell
do shell script "open -a google\\ chrome"
```

`set frontmost to true` and `activate` would also raise other windows. `set index to 1` doesn't actually raise the window, but it makes it appear as window 1 to System Events, which can `AXRaise` it. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for different ways to assign shortcuts to scripts.

This would select a window by the URLs of tabs:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        tell w
            repeat with t in tabs
                if URL of t contains "google" then
                    set index to 1
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the great response!

Comment: Starting from 10.9 Mavericks, `perform action "AXRaise" of window 1` will require [explicit permission](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6026) to run. This message will appear: ["Your App would like to control this computer using accessibility features."](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT6026/en_US/HT6026_controlprompt-en.png)