# On Windows, how to set a keyboard-shortcut for focusing a process' window?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, task-switching

Scenario: I have open Firefox A and Firefox B and putty A and putty B.

I'd like to be able to attach a custom global keyboard shortcut for focusing either of these windows. For example, set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to focus putty B (other shortcuts are suitable, too).

I can set the title of the windows if must, or I can launch the processes in a specific order. Or anything that works even for one session (PIDs, etc.).

On Mac this is said to [be possible](https://superuser.com/questions/586806/how-to-switch-to-a-certain-window-in-os-x-opposed-to-application-switching-usi/586862#586862) with [Witch](http://alternativeto.net/software/witch/?platform=windows&license=free) but how to do it with Windows?

Comment: In Windows 7 and 8 the first 10 icons on the task bar have the shortcuts Win+1 through Win+0.

Comment: @Brian this is a great option, wish I'd thought of that! Grouped windows are cycling is there a way to directly address them? I suppose I can just turn off grouping. For record: Answers about more bendable options are still welcome of course! :)