# Save a webpage on the desktop and label it red using Automator

Tags: macos, google-chrome, automator

In Chrome, I use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save a webpage and another separate shortcut I created using Services (Automator) to label files red on the desktop (does not have specificity for `.webloc` files).

However, this is what I would like to do with one keyboard shortcut (either a Workflow or Service):

1. Drag and drop the favicon onto desktop as `.webloc` file
2. Label it red

I would love to start learning how to use Automator more effectively for these tasks, and any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell tab 1 of window 1
    set u to URL
    set t to title
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    make new internet location file at desktop to u with properties {name:t}
    set label index of result to 2
end tell
```

Or use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php):

[image]