# Assign keyboard shortcut to pause music in website

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, media-keys

I use [saavn.com](http://www.saavn.com) for listening to bollywood music. It's a great service but they don't have native mac app so I can't control it using keyboard media keys.

There must be a way to use keyboard media keys to control all music.

Comment: It's generally difficult/impossible to intercept the special KB media keys. Using a custom [userscript](http://userscripts.org) you should be able to inject JS into the page that will assign keyboard shortcuts to the various play/pause etc. functions. I doubt such a script already exists for this site, but you never know. There might also be scripts for similar sites that can be suitably modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in documents
        tell t
            if URL starts with "http://www.saavn.com/" then
                do JavaScript "e = document.querySelectorAll('#pause:not(.hide)')[0] || document.querySelectorAll('#play:not(.hide)')[0]; e.click()"
                exit repeat
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

A similar script for YouTube and Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t
            if URL starts with "http://www.youtube.com" then
                execute javascript "player = document.querySelectorAll('#player embed')[0]
if (player) {
    player.getPlayerState() == 1 ? player.pauseVideo() : player.playVideo()
} else { // if youtube.com/html5 is enabled
    document.querySelectorAll('.html5-player-chrome > button:first-child')[0].click()
}"
                exit repeat
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: the query selector string no longer works. use `embed#movie_player`.

Comment: @thisisadeadend Thanks, I replaced `#watch7-player embed` with `#player embed`.

Comment: I've made a few more scripts for some common youtube actions and put them up here https://gist.github.com/fent/7763775 enjoy

Comment: Can't upvote this enough.

Comment: I couldn't get this script to work for Safari nor the one you posted in AskDifferent. But the script in your github page worked fine. You might want to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the keyboard part I would use [keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) - this will allow you to intercept media keys. I can also launch scripts for keypresses (@lauri-rantas answer covers that nicely). Unfortunately it also needs some coding to adjust it to ones needs.

What I like about it is:

- you will even be to override the media keys and "caps-lock"
- one can also differenciate between left-shift, control, command keys and the corresponding right ones
- the remappings can depend on which app is in foreground - so your mapping won't interfere with other media players