# Lock OSX with keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

OSX machines have a keyboard shortcut to put the machine to sleep, which suspends processing, downloads, and other operations.

OSX machines also have a Lock function which can be triggered via a menu option. It can also be triggered by running a specific command: `/System/Library/CoreServices/"Menu Extras"/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

How can I lock my OSX machine with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I have previously set up an Automator "service" to run the above command in a bash script triggered by a specific shortcut, but that no longer seems to work. Choosing the Service from the (Application) menu does nothing. Issuing the command directly works.

Answer (score 4):

The default is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>

Note: If you have a newer mac without a disc drive, replace <kbd>Eject</kbd> with the <kbd>Power</kbd> button.

The screen locks and turns off, but the computer is still running.

Comment: I believed that the shortcut you posted caused the machine to sleep, but that doesn't seem to be the case--processing does seem to continue in the background.

Comment: Yeah, it puts the display to sleep and locks it (assuming you have that option set up).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a shortcut to `CGSession -suspend` with an application like [Alfred or FastScripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943).

If you have the Alfred Powerpack, you can assign a shortcut for the lock action:

[image]

Or you can use control-shift-eject (or control-shift-power) if you enable this setting from the Security & Privacy preference pane:

[image]