# Is there a way to automatically save the image in a browser as the webpage's title?

Tags: macos, download, tags

For example: The webpage title is `Student Cookbook (The Australian Women&#39;s Weekly Minis): Amazon.de`. Any image that you save would be named accordingly. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible.

If you want to make copying the titles of pages easier, you could [assign a keyboard shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Safari" to set the clipboard to (get name of document 1)
```