# How to automate shell script to run when I open a particular app in OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, node.js, brackets

I've been running into a rut recently with one project I've been trying to accomplish. Using Automator, but I don't know how to exactly to go about this project. There's this script editing app called Brackets, and I want to make it so whenever the app is opened, the shell command known as tty.js is executed. Any help I can get would be great

Answer (score 4):

What you can try is going to the application's .app folder and renaming the binary, creating a script file (marked executable) named as the executable used to be which will contain a reference the now-renamed executable along with whatever you are scripting.  e.g.

```
cd /Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS
mv Brackets BracketsReal
echo "tty.js" > Brackets
echo "BracketsReal &" >> Brackets
chmod +x Brackets
```

That should create a text script that launches your script and the app afterwards...

**edit**

scripts in `Appname.app/Contents/MacOS/` folder are supported.

The first line `#!/bin/sh` (aka `shebang`) **is required**

The technique to move the real executable and make it execute from a script is called `wrapping` and is also used from applications like Gimp or XQuartz (Xorg/X11) on MacOS.

If I understand correctly what the user was trying to achieve, run Bracket and automatically open the file `tty.js`, apart the missing `shebang`, need some other consideration.

To correctly wrap BracketsReal, Brackets should be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "$(dirname "$0")/BracketsReal"
```

That's should run as if we never moved Brackets to BracketsReal.

`exec` is a built-in command of the shell

`$0` is a special argument passed from the system to the executed shell script, when executed with a *click* should be the full path to the script:

`/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets`

`dirname` is a shell command to get only the directory part without the file name, `$( )` is a command substitution, once executed the line will become:

```
exec /Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/BracketsReal
```

So much so we can move the application from `/Applications` in other folders and still should run it.

At this point we should check that `BracketsReal` (probably a script itself) accept files to open as arguments on the command line (and eventually if require some special syntax) if it does accept arguments then the line would become something like:

```
exec "$(dirname "$0")/BracketsReal" "/path/to/the/file/tty.js"
```

Last note, to check if something is wrong with the wrapper script just open a terminal and run the wrapper, at the terminal prompt just type/paste:

```
/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets
```

privilegies or syntax errors are printed in the terminal window.

Comment: Thanks! I had one problem though. When running those commands in terminal, I kept getting the message "-bash: !/bin/sh": event not found" after trying to execute "echo "#!/bin/sh" > Brackets"

Comment: Aha, ok then omit that line.  Edit the file in a text editor and delete that top line.  Response edited.

Comment: I have one other issue as well. Whenever I type in the "mv" command I get this as well "mv: rename Brackets to BracketsReal: No such file or directory" I have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: I haven't been on OSX in a while, sorry.  Try:  `cd /Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS` first

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for all your help though. Unfortunately, I just get this message everytime I try to open the app now after the changes. "You can’t open the application “Brackets” because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

Comment: Grr.  To change it back, do this:  `cd /Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS ;
cp BracketsReal Brackets`

Comment: Thanks to @EkriirkE's answer I discovered that scripts were supported, so added some info, I'm still a MacOS newbie

Answer (score 2):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) has an option to run a macro when an application is launched:

[image]

You might also [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like `open -a Brackets;tty.js` and then always use that script to open Brackets.