# how do I create a file in a directory in Finder on the Mac?

Tags: mac, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to create a new text file in a Finder window on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/14118/easiest-way-to-create-a-new-text-file-in-a-finder-window-on-osx)

On Windows in Explorer I can right click and e.g. create a text file.

On the mac when I right-click, I can create "new folder" but I can't create a text file. So I have to go find my text editor, do file new and create one, then navigate to where I want to save it: 5-10 steps instead of 1.

**How can I just create a text file in a directory in Finder?**

[image]

like on windows:

[image]

Comment: Everett's answer is a great solution. But note that you can reduce the 5-10 steps by opening the folder you want, opening the text editor, and when you save, drag the folder from Finder into the *Save* dialog box. It will then automatically navigate to that folder.

Comment: OSX: 1. Open the editor (new document is automatically generated, or if already open, create a new one) 3. Save and specify folder. Windows: 1. Specify folder 2. Create new file 3. Open the file. Exactly the same number of steps. You'd quickly get used to it if you tried. Also, you can drag&drop files and folders into open&save dialogs, which changes their location instead of moving them there.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you would do that? I don't see a use case right off. In any case, I'd just `touch` from the command line, but that is not what you asked for.

Comment: the use case is just to "create any kind of file where you currently are", e.g. a word file or text file or excel file, and not have to go find the application, start it, save, then navigate back to where you want to create the file in the first place and save it there.

Comment: This question is, "how do I get the same functionality out of OS X, that I have in Windows."  The other question is the best practice for doing something in OS X.  This question is about any file type, the other one is just about txt files.  I recommend leaving this solution for search purposes.

Comment: @Everett, true, but the answers at the other question are not limited to just text files. (And closing as a duplicate does not remove either question; it just creates a second entry point.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/02/create_new_file.html

Not affiliated with the site, but this is a free solution.

What works for me is Launch bar.  I hit command space, type txt, then hit enter and TextMate (or OS X's built in TextEditor) opens.  I paste in, or type what I need to, and shift command S.  I'm asked where I want to save my file.  I don't see much difference between what I do, and navigating to where I want to put something, building an empty file there, and then open it with the software.  Especially considering I can do my method without taking my hands off the keyboard to use the mouse at all.  Also I can do this with any program, not just a text editor (Aperture, StarCraft2, Mail, PowerPoint, etc)